# Android ListView on click maps marker of specific coordinates

Tags: java, android

devs just a quick solution to the problem. I have a static listview of different highways and Maps activity. Now functionality I want to implement is that when the user clicks on any highway which is present in the listview markers are displayed on the map. Same functionality like e.g there is a list of known places like FB HQ Eifel tower etc when the user clicks on the button the marker moves to a particular location. I just want this kind of functionality through listview. What I have done so far is given below.
My list Coding:

```js
public class Motorway_List extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView list;


        String[] maintitle ={
                "Motorway 1","Motorway 2",
                "Motorway 3",
                "Motorway 9"
        };

        Integer[] imgid={
                R.drawable.1,R.drawable.2,
                R.drawable.3,R.drawable.9,
                
        };
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_motorway__list);

        Motorway_list_adapter adapter=new Motorway_list_adapter(this, maintitle,imgid);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(position == 0) {
                    //code specific to first list item
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your First Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//this is where I call maps activity but it's open full map activity I want to click to open specific markers.
                    i = new Intent(Motorway_List.this,EmergencyMapsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                else if(position == 1) {
                    //code specific to 2nd list item
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your Second Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else if(position == 2) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your Third Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(position == 3) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your Forth Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(position == 4) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your Fifth Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And My maps Coding:

```js
public class EmergencyMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
        {
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1 ;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        enableMyLocation();
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng islamabad = new LatLng(33.692390, 73.055848);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(islamabad).title("Marker in Islamabad"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(islamabad,10f));
    }


    private void enableMyLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                            {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // Check if location permissions are granted and if so enable the
        // location data layer.
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0]
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    enableMyLocation();
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Motorway_List extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView list;


        String[] maintitle ={
                "Motorway 1","Motorway 2",
                "Motorway 3",
                "Motorway 9"
        };

        Integer[] imgid={
                R.drawable.1,R.drawable.2,
                R.drawable.3,R.drawable.9,

        };
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_motorway__list);

        Motorway_list_adapter adapter=new Motorway_list_adapter(this, maintitle,imgid);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //TODO SENDING POSITION WHICH ITEM IS CLICK to MAP ACTIVITY
                    i = new Intent(Motorway_List.this,EmergencyMapsActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("which",position);
                    startActivity(i);

        });
    }
}
```

Seconde Activity

```
      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int position = (int) bundle.get("which");
    if (position==0){
       // motoway 1 Coding
    }else if (position==1){
        //motorway 2 coding
    }else if(position ==2){
        //motorway 3 coding
    }else if(position == 3){
        //motoway 4 coding
    }
}
```